# Laptop (Windows 8.1) corrupts several usb keys

Tags: linux, usb, windows-8.1

Since a few days ago, my brother's laptop (Win8.1) cannot recognize any usb drive (but works ok with peripherals such as his mouse and keyboard). The problem is that usb keys plugged onto his laptop cannot be recognized by any other computer in the household (whether using windows 7 or Linux Mint).

If plugged in a Windows computer, they look like an empy card reader. They show along other drives but seen as empty (and don't show in drive manager).

If plugged in a Linux computer, they cannot be mounted either and GParted shows an Input/ouptu error while reading.

Is it possible that the laptop "fried" the usb keys on a hardware level?

Comment: First thought was a virus doing funny things to the USB's, but if linux shows real read errors in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` (not just a gparted "funny format"-type error, which could result from funny data having been written to the drives) I suppose the damage is possible from a really messed up laptop. **Stop** plugging different usb drives into it, possibly destroying them, until you're sure they can be recovered

Answer (score 0):

Most likely issue is that the user wrote to the USB drive and forgot to eject it. Try doing a *full* format (not *quick* format) of the drive on a Windows PC. FAT32 is best for smaller drives, exFAT for *very* large drives or if you plan to have files greater than a couple of GB.

Needless to say, that will erase all data.

It *is* possible that ESD or other cause destroyed it, or that it has worn out (flash ram has a large but  finite number of writes it can accept).

Comment: If it wasn't ejected properly, then it's likely just the filesystem that needs repairing. `chkdsk` (or `fsck` tools) should work, likely to recover some/all the data too. And a quick format should definitely create a new filesystem, why overwrite the entire device (with a limited lifetime of writes)?

Comment: @Xen2050: "Limited" > 100,000. It's best to completely reformat when there's a severe issue, as one does not want a hidden error to recur. My experience has been that quick format is ineffective.

Comment: According to many sources, even Wikipedia, the common (i.e. cheap) USB drives "limited writes" <= 3,000 with some even 1,000. And *"Regardless of the endurance of the memory itself, the USB connector hardware is specified to withstand only around 1,500 insert-removal cycles"*. But, the question shows no evidence that multiple USB drives would coincidentally all fail by themselves, so they're not recognized at all, immediately after being used on this suspect laptop.

Comment: Whether on Windows or Linux, it's impossible to format the usb drives. Windows reads it as an empty drive (like an empty SD card reader) and GParted shows this input/output error.

Two usb drives were "fried" simultaneously and my brother tells me that he wasn't able to access the flash drives at all, let alone eject them.
One of them is a brand new SanDisk Extreme. I guess it's unlikely it worn out in two weeks.

It looks like the usb ports ont the laptop are damaged somehow, and cause this malfunction.